# extract nouns and verbs using NLTK

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, nltk

I have django rest application and a model Task. I am absolutely new to natural processing and I want to build a function that returns me list of nouns and verbs. It looks something like this:

```
@api_view(['GET'])        
def noun_verb_list(request):

    nouns = []
    verbs = []
    """
    List all nouns and verbs from available tasks
    """
    if request.query_params.get('projectId'):
            # get a specific project 
            projectId = request.query_params.get('projectId')
            project = Project.objects.get(id=projectId)
            tasks = project.project_tasks.all()

            # extract nouns and verbs from tasks here


            return Response(# return appropriate nouns)
```

Could someone help me build this function? What to import and with logic?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `nltk` [pos-tagger](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html)

```
>>> import nltk
>>> text = nltk.word_tokenize("They refuse to permit us to obtain the refuse permit")
>>> pos_tagged = nltk.pos_tag(text)
>>> pos_tagged
[('They', 'PRP'), ('refuse', 'VBP'), ('to', 'TO'), ('permit', 'VB'), ('us', 'PRP'),
('to', 'TO'), ('obtain', 'VB'), ('the', 'DT'), ('refuse', 'NN'), ('permit', 'NN')]
>>> nouns = filter(lambda x:x[1]=='NN',pos_tagged)
>>> nouns
[('refuse', 'NN'), ('permit', 'NN')]
```

Nouns are marked by `NN` and verbs are by `VB`, so you can use them accordingly.

**NOTE:**
If you have not setup/downloaded `punkt` and `averaged_perceptron_tagger` with nltk, you might have to do that using:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. this nltk.download() I have to run through command  line or is there a way through pip or similar?

Comment: @Nitish kindly upvote and accept the answer if this helped.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Is there a way to input more than one tag into the lamba filter or does it only accept one tag at a time?

Comment: Ooop! Answered my own question: Counter(list(filter(lambda x: (x[1] == 'VB' or x[1] == 'VBP'), tagged))).most_common(20)